# Как передать в поток параметр?

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Создав поток с помощью API функции CreateThread и передав ему параметр, как можно в делфи принять или извлечь этот параметр?

Comment: Спасибо! Ошибка была в стандартах вызова. Надо было указать STDCALL.

Comment: @Naruto Не забудьте принять (галочка) правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передача параметра в поток осуществляется примерно так:

```
type
    TSomething = class
        public
        Z: Integer;
    end;

function ThreadProc(p: Pointer) : DWORD; stdcall;
begin
    { Собственно здесь идет прием параметра }
    Result := TSomething(p).Z;
end;

var
    id: DWORD;
    h: THandle;
    s: TSomething;
begin
    s := TSomething.Create;
    s.Z := 0;

    h := CreateThread(nil, 0, @ThreadProc, Pointer(s), 0, id);

    WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE); 
end.
```

Но вообще в Delphi правильнее использовать TThread вместо CreateThread.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого есть специальный аргумент в данной функции - lpParameter. То есть можно передать указатель на переменную или инициализированную структуру, а в потоке использовать эти значения для совершения необходимых действий.

Передавать его просто - сделать операцию получения адреса.
Получить его - присвоить адрес своей переменной и сделать разыменование адреса.

```
var Nya: ^Integer;
A: Integer;
...
K := lpParam; // присваивание
...
A = 10 + K^; // использование
```

И вместо CreateThread лучше в Delphi BeginThread использовать.

Глобальные переменные, конечно, тоже можно, но там надо аккуратнее.

Answer (score 0):

Через глобальные переменные: [создание потоков с помощью функции CreateThread](http://www.codingrus.ru/readarticle.php?article_id=1998).

А по мне в делфи лучше использовать Thread Object: [основы работы с потоками в Delphi](http://www.realcoding.net/article/view/101).